# First parameter in Mysqli Query is null

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

I have this problem, when i am printing the second parameter from mysqli query it prints out the query to be performed but when i print the first parameter it prints nothing and when I perform the query it produces an error and it cannot insert the data into database. Here's my code:

```
            $Insert_Patient_Data = "INSERT INTO patient_account(P_Password,P_Fname,P_Lname,P_Mname,P_Age,P_Gender,P_Email) 
            VALUES('$Encrypted_Password', '$Inputted_First_Name', '$Inputted_Last_Name', '$Inputted_Middle_Name', '$Inputted_Age', '$Inputted_Gender', '$Inputted_Email')";

            $Patient_Query = mysqli_query($Connection, $Insert_Patient_Data);

            if(!$Patient_Query)
                echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'> alert('Error: Database Connection error. Please try again Later.') </script>";
            else
                echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'> alert('Succesfully Registered.') </script>";
```

1. I tried to print the second parameter which is $Insert_Patient_Data , it prints the query. there is nothing wrong in the output.
2. I tried to print the first paramter which is $Connection and it gives an error: **Recoverable fatal error: Object of class MySQLi could not be converted to string**
3. I tried to print the $Patient_Query but it prints nothing, even the second parameter (which is $Insert_Patient_Data) became null at this line.
4. At this time i tried to perform the $Patient_Query (Not printing it) and it goes to the **if(!$Patient_Query)** decision.

**Question:** Why it becomes a null? and what happens? and what is the solution on it? There are some queries on this page accessing the same table but they had no problem.

P.S. i checked the table name and column names from the database and they are all okay. I also included the System_Connector.php (Where the connection to database and the variable $connection is declared).

Comment: You can't echo out a mysqli connection, because it's an object. You can use `var_dump()` or `print_r()`, but I really wouldn't recommend it. You just need to make sure it's not null or false. I'd really recommend checking for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to find out **why** a query has failed.

Comment: If `!$Patient_Query` is true then there was an error executing the query.  Use `mysqli_error($Connection)` to see what that error was.  Since your code is wide open to SQL injection, you could be trying to execute any variety of broken syntax or invalid SQL.  It's likely that correcting the SQL injection vulnerability will render your current error moot.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur, and you'll never have to worry about stray apostrophes ever again.**

Comment: I used the var_dump that @aynber and i saw the error... i just changed the default value for the foreign key to another table and it solved the entire error. Thank you so much! yours was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

var_dump($Connection) will show you have a mysqli object, you cant echo objects!

Anyway, call `mysqli_error($Connection)` if it fails http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

```
$Patient_Query = mysqli_query($Connection, $Insert_Patient_Data) or die(mysqli_error($Connection));
```

Or even:

```
    if(!$Patient_Query = mysqli_query($Connection, $Insert_Patient_Data);)
        //fail
    else
       // pass
```

Comment: when i tried $Patient_Query = mysqli_query($Connection, $Insert_Patient_Data) or die(mysqli_error()); it produces this: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given. The null is the $Connection , but i don't know the reason why it became a null.

Comment: oops, edited - you need to pass connection into mysqli_error!